# Info.plist: Do I need to specify 'Document Types' for text files used in app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, info.plist

I am trying to set up xxx-Info.plist for my app. I am using a bunch of text files in my app.

Here is my question: Do I need to specify in 'Document Types'?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

No. You dont need to specify document types in info.plist.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I feel better now!

Comment: @boochan224 Welcome. Please accept the answer if you got the solution of your issue, so that others can use this answer for there same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify document types in Info.plist only if you want to associate some document types with your app. (For example Adobe Reader is associated with pdf files)